# Delegate partial function in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates, partial

I've written some calculate delegates which are passed as parameters.

```
private delegate int CalculateDelegator(int value1, int value2);
CalculateDelegator addWith = add;
CalculateDelegator divWith = div;

private static int add(int value1, int value2) {
    return value1 + value2;
}

private static int div(int value1, int value2) {
    return value1 / value2;
}
```

The method `link(CalculateDelegator method, int value2)` which receives `addWith` as parameter holds value1 and the method which calls `link` holds value2. So I call link() always with passing value2 as seperate paremeter.

Is there a way of passing the calculating method including the first parameter: `link(addWith(value2))`?
 (e.g. as a partial function like in Scala)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, something like that isn't directly possible in C#.

What you can do is something like the following:

```
int link(Func<int, int> addWithValue2)
{
    return addWithValue2(value1);
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
link(v1 => addWith(v1, value2));
```

BTW: I think the concept you are describing is called currying and there is a project that tries to bring it to C#: https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageCurry. It basically uses the approach shown in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
Func<int, int> partialMethod =
    value1 => addWith(value1, 5);
```

This way the `partialMethod` will take in one argument and passes it with the internal 'holded' value.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you would need to create an extension method for `int`:

```
public static LinkExtension
{
    public static void Link(this int value, CalculateDelegator method)
    {
        // Link action here
    }
}
```

So you just call `value2.Link(addWith)`.